# Exception decimal.ConversionSyntax not caught

Tags: python, exception

This appears to be a simple Python question but it's got me scratching my head.  I would expect the following code to print "Caught [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]".

Instead of the specific `except decimal.ConversionSyntax` exception handler being called, it falls through to the generic `except Exception as ex` and prints out "Exception [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>] not caught in previous except clause".

Am I missing something obvious?  Appreciate any insights -- thanks!

```
import decimal

amount = 'this is not a valid decimal string'

try:
    amount = decimal.Decimal(amount).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'))
except decimal.ConversionSyntax as cex:
    print(f'Caught {cex}')
except Exception as ex:
    print(f'Exception {ex} not caught in previous except clause')
```

Running the code:

```
$ python3 /tmp/decimal-exception.py 
Exception [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>] not caught in previous except clause
```

Comment: It seems to throw a `decimal.InvalidOperation`, not directly a `decimal.ConversionSyntax`.

Answer (score 1):

Some diagnostics:

```
>>> try:
...   decimal.Decimal(amount)
... except Exception as e:
...   f = e
...
>>> f
InvalidOperation([<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>])
>>> f.__class__
<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>
```

`decimal.InvalidOperation` is the class you should actually be looking for. Even though the string representation of the exception mentions `decimal.ConversionSyntax`, and that is indeed a subclass of `decimal.InvalidOperation`, the base class is raised.

Comment: Perfect response -- thank you so much for the insight into how the exception returns its string representation.  Catching the `InvalidOperation` exception was what I was looking for.  Thanks again!